# Material design on android 4 strange bug

Tags: android, layout

I have app with target sdk 22 made in material design. Everything works fine on lollipop and marshmallow. But today I tested it on 4.x and that what I get 
[image: bug]

[image: bug2]

It happened also when I click anything like toolbar button etc. once I have the same bug on lollipop but I thought it some rly weird rare event.  Please help

**Content Create Order**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activity.orders.CreateOrderActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_create_order"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Выберите категорию заявки"
                    android:id="@+id/textView17"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/catsspinner"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/etcomment"
                    android:hint="Кол-во тонн/часов, материал и т.д"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:paddingTop="12dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="12dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Контактная информация"
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Номер телефона клиента будет виден только тому исполнителю, кто взял заявку."
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/etphone"
                    android:hint="Телефон клиента"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                    android:paddingTop="12dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Общая информация"
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >

                    <uvee.sapron.helpers.DelayAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/book_title"
                        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionSearch"
                        android:hint="Конечный адрес заявки"
                        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:paddingTop="12dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="12dp" />

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"/>
                </FrameLayout>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/etprice"
                    android:hint="Цена (в рублях)"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:paddingTop="12dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="12dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Ваша комиссия (в рублях)"
                    android:id="@+id/etcomission"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                    android:paddingTop="12dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Ваш номер карты для комиссии"
                    android:id="@+id/etcardname"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                    android:maxLength="19"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/etdate"
                    android:hint="Дата выполнения"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:paddingTop="12dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity create order**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activity.orders.CreateOrderActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_create_order" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post some code of your layout's xml file. It seems as if the problem as to do with your supportV7 library. I cannot confirm this without some code

Comment: @NizaSiwale

http://pastebin.com/YwL27T4Z  - Content Create Order
http://pastebin.com/4JWzDcV5 - Activity create order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue when updated my Android Studio to version 2.2 alpha. Just go back to 1.6 and fix gradle build version.

Answer (score 1):

Have you used cardview as background? because on pre-lollipop devices cardview adds image as a shadow background.

Comment: I used appbar layout and coordinator layout which include another layout

Answer (score 0):

I think its issue with your your background you have set to the Views. It expending due to the screen resolutions. Show your Xml code.

Comment: It happens when it should show material on click animation

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YwL27T4Z  - Content Create Order
http://pastebin.com/4JWzDcV5 - Activity create order